# How to check all the items of an CheckboxGroupInput

Tags: react-admin

We want to use the CheckboxGroupInput with many choices.
And we want to add a custom checkbox to check all the items at once.

```
<CheckboxGroupInput source="targets" label="Cibles" choices={targets} 
onChange={this.handleAll} />
```

We want to add a custom checkbox (with label 'All') and when we check this custom checkbox all the others checkboxes from the same group were checked or not.

Comment: Did you try to implement something? Please share us the code, so that we can help you fix it. As a start, you can read [write your own input](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component) and the [actual `CheckboxGroupInput` code](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/d79410c8cfc80fcf07dbd13c21f8ffe6b959aea1/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/input/CheckboxGroupInput.js).